# Like a page in facebook from my application and getting feedback

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent, share

I've seen some games and apps having a feature that enables you to like the app Facebook page inside the app. (or sharing the app website link)

I've read similar questions about sharing on Facebook by intent and I'm enable to share a text on Facebook now. but my question is **how can I create like button and how can I get feedback that a user has liked or shared my app on Facebook?**

Please help me in details because I have very little knowledge about intents and Facebook sdk.

Comment: What platform do you use?

Comment: @YervandKhalapyan: You mean my android api? if so min target is 8.